# Scala - XML parsing tag not working properly

Tags: xml, scala

I'm very new to Scala and I'm trying to parse a xml file to convert it into a csv in order to be furtherly processed by another scala program.
In this xml file, I have tags like this :

```
    <Event EventTime="2018-12-25T22:26:58" ProfileID="0031053794_0">
        <StreamEvent>
            <Stream streamId="160" streamType="Video"/>
            <Stream streamId="80" streamType="Audio"/>
            <Stream streamId="0" streamType="Data"/>
        </StreamEvent>
    </Event>
```

My concern is about catching the 3 stream ID in differents variables.

I've tried this code :

```
def getStreamId(Event: Node, StreamType: String) = {
 //To improve -- Using head , (1) and last can cause trouble if the order changes in the file

      if (StreamType == "Video") {
        val StreamID = (Event \ "_" \ "Stream" \\ "@streamId").head.text
        StreamID
      } else if (StreamType == "Audio") {
        val StreamID = (Event \ "_" \ "Stream" \\ "@streamId")(1).text
        StreamID
      } else {
        val StreamID = (Event \ "_" \ "Stream" \\ "@streamId").last.text
        StreamID
      }

    }
```

(I know this code is gonna give me the same value for each StreamType but I think about using a first part which will be like val Type = (Event \ "*" \ "Stream" \ "@StreamType").filter(* == Streamtype) once it is working to have the correct value of each stream type.)
This one is working well but I've 2 problems with this code :

1. As I wrote in comment, this won't work if the order of the stream tags changes in the file
2. I also have Events where there is no  tags. In this case, I got an error while running my code because "head", "(1)" and "last" can't be used on an empty object

That's why I used this code :

```
def getStreamId(Event: Node, StreamType: String) = {

      if (StreamType == "Video") {
        val StreamID = (Event \ "_" \ "Stream" \\ "@streamId").text
        StreamID
      } else if (StreamType == "Audio") {
        val StreamID = (Event \ "_" \ "Stream" \\ "@streamId").text
        StreamID
      } else {
        val StreamID = (Event \ "_" \ "Stream" \\ "@streamId").text
        StreamID
      }

    }
```

The result of this code is : StreamID is the same for both case and equal to 160800 (then, the concatenation of each StreamID)

For those reasons, I've tried the following code :

```
if (StreamType == "Video") {
        val StreamID= (Event \ "_" \ "Stream" \ "@streamId").text
        StreamID
      } else if (StreamType == "Audio") {
        val StreamID = (Event \ "_" \ "Stream" \ "@streamId").text
        StreamID
      } else {
        val StreamID = (Event \ "_" \ "Stream" \ "@streamId").text
        StreamID
      }
```

Unfortunately, with this code, nothing is returned, even when there are  tags. I can't see where the problem is with this last code because I follow the exact order of the file tags.

I call the getStreamID function with :

```
val StreamId_Video = getStreamId(Event, "Video")
val StreamId_Audio = getStreamId(Event, "Audio")
val StreamId_Data = getStreamId(Event, "Data")
```

To summarize, my question is : why this code :

```
val StreamID= (Event \ "_" \ "Stream" \ "@streamId").text
```

is not returning anything ?

Then , my expected ouput is :
StreamId_Video = 160, StreamId_Audio = 80 and StreamId_Data = 0

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on another forum, here is the right code to write :

```
def getStreamId(Event: Node, StreamType: String): Option[String] = {
  (Event \ "_" \ "Stream")
    .find(_ \@ "streamType" == StreamType)
    .map(_ \@ "streamId")
}
```

Now, to call the function, I just need to do this :

```
val StreamId_Video = getStreamId(Event, "Video").getOrElse("")
val StreamId_Audio = getStreamId(Event, "Audio").getOrElse("")
val StreamId_Data = getStreamId(Event, "Data").getOrElse("")
```